# Symfony run through a JSON file

Tags: php, json, database, symfony

My error is : Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

I would like to save entities in my data base. I succeed only if I put one element in JSON file but I want to run through the JSON file and save all elements. I can not do a loop.

I have a JSON File like this :

```
[
    {
        "nom": "tablette",
        "url": "http://www.cdiscount.com/opa.aspx/?trackingid=idXtspN-9-e2eKH4rjay8tNG2NeGkp5QZdUVk2714qK1CHkFJHIjbIK2itfMOQIL&action=product&id=MD513NFA&offerid=175431240",
        "prix": 199.9900,
        "description": "Tablette tactile avec écran 9,7\" capacitif - Processeur Apple A6X bicoeur avec processeur graphique quadricoeur- Stockage 16Go - WiFi 802.11 b/g/n - Camera avant 1,2Mpixels - Caméra arrière 5Mpixels - Connecteur Lightning reversible - Jusqu’à 10h d'autonomie - Garantie 1 an",
        "image": "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/N/F/A/1/700x700/MD513NFA.jpg"
    },
    {
        "nom": "autre",
        "url": "http://www.cdiscount.com/opa.aspx/?trackingid=idXtspN-9-e2eKH4rjay8tNG2NeGkp5QZdUVk2714qK1CHkFJHIjbIK2itfMOQIL&action=product&id=MD513NFA&offerid=175431240",
        "prix": 20.0,
        "description": "Autre Tablette tactile avec écran 9,7\" capacitif - Processeur Apple A6X bicoeur avec processeur graphique quadricoeur- Stockage 16Go - WiFi 802.11 b/g/n - Camera avant 1,2Mpixels - Caméra arrière 5Mpixels - Connecteur Lightning reversible - Jusqu’à 10h d'autonomie - Garantie 1 an",
        "image": "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/N/F/A/1/700x700/MD513NFA.jpg"
    }
]
```

Below my code in Symfony 4 :

```
public function store(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $jsonRecu =file_get_contents("api.json");
    $someArray = json_decode($jsonRecu, true);
    print_r($someArray);
    foreach ($someArray as $item) {
        $article=  $serializer->deserialize($item, Article::class, 'json');
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->json($article, 201, []);
    }
}
```

the content of $jsonRecu when I do var_dump($jsonRecu); is :

```
string(1260) "[ { "nom": "tablette", "url": "http://www.cdiscount.com/opa.aspx/?trackingid=idXtspN-9-e2eKH4rjay8tNG2NeGkp5QZdUVk2714qK1CHkFJHIjbIK2itfMOQIL&action=product&id=MD513NFA&offerid=175431240", "prix": 199.9900, "description": "Tablette tactile avec écran 9,7\" capacitif - Processeur Apple A6X bicoeur avec processeur graphique quadricoeur- Stockage 16Go - WiFi 802.11 b/g/n - Camera avant 1,2Mpixels - Caméra arrière 5Mpixels - Connecteur Lightning reversible - Jusqu’à 10h d'autonomie - Garantie 1 an", "image": "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/N/F/A/1/700x700/MD513NFA.jpg" }, { "nom": "autre", "url": "http://www.cdiscount.com/opa.aspx/?trackingid=idXtspN-9-e2eKH4rjay8tNG2NeGkp5QZdUVk2714qK1CHkFJHIjbIK2itfMOQIL&action=product&id=MD513NFA&offerid=175431240", "prix": 20.0, "description": "Autre Tablette tactile avec écran 9,7\" capacitif - Processeur Apple A6X bicoeur avec processeur graphique quadricoeur- Stockage 16Go - WiFi 802.11 b/g/n - Camera avant 1,2Mpixels - Caméra arrière 5Mpixels - Connecteur Lightning reversible - Jusqu’à 10h d'autonomie - Garantie 1 an", "image": "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/N/F/A/1/700x700/MD513NFA.jpg" } ]"
```

**EDIT**

the code below works fine :

```
 public function store(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $jsonRecu =file_get_contents("api.json");
        $arrayOfProperObjects = $serializer->deserialize($jsonRecu, Article::class.'[]', 'json');
        var_dump($arrayOfProperObjects);
        foreach ($arrayOfProperObjects as $article) {
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();

        }
        return $this->json($article, 201, []);
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the content of `$jsonRecu` ? use `var_dump($jsonRecu);`

Comment: I don't think that error is coming from the code shown above.

Comment: Where is the line and file of the error? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @Nelly So it's `$data` that's that it's complaining about, not `$jsonRecu`.  Nothing in the top part of your question seems to be relevant.  So now you need to show us the contents of `$data` and explain what you are expecting `json_decode($data, $associative, $recursionDepth, $options);` to do.

Comment: @PatrickQ Nelly provided the code inside the symfony deserializer, not the line in their code that caused the error, which would have to be the `$serializer->deserialize()` call. their added code certainly didn't help. the problem is caused by the deserialize call expecting a string, while json_decode already turned the whole string into an array of arrays, thus providing an array to the deserialize call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll split your code into pieces and explain what happens.

```
public function store(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $jsonRecu = file_get_contents("api.json");
```

at this point, $jsonRecu contains a string. that's fine.

```
    $someArray = json_decode($jsonRecu, true);
```

here `$someArray` contains the **completely decoded objects, i.e. an array of arrays**.

```
    print_r($someArray);
    foreach ($someArray as $item) {
        $article=  $serializer->deserialize($item, Article::class, 'json');
```

and this is where the problem is. `$item` obviously is not a string. Deserializing always expects a string. thus the error message. (I will skip the fact, that you return after the first article, completely ignoring the second article in the process ...)

now to fix this:

#### option 1: use the serializer to deserialize `$jsonRecu`

the serializer is perfectly capable of deserializing an array of objects from a json-encoded string, the relevant portion in the docs is this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays which tells you, that you have to add `[]` to the class name, so:

```
$arrayOfProperObjects = $serializer->deserialize($jsonRecu, Article::class.'[]', 'json');
foreach($arrayOfProperObjects as $article) {
    $em->persist($article);
    // ...
}
```

#### option 2: use a denormalizer instead

in `$someArray` every `$item` is an `$array` itself. deserializing works on strings though. However, deserializing in symfony works in two steps: 1. decoding, 2. denormalizing, where decoding turns a `string` (serialized) into an `array` (normalized), and the denormalizing turns the `array` into a proper object. Since you already have the array - which hopefully conforms to the expected normalized format - you should be able to turn it into a proper object by calling `denormalize` instead.

```
    foreach ($someArray as $item) {
        $article = $serializer->denormalize($item, Article::class);
        // etc. ...
```

there are obviously other options like ... re-encode the `$item` into json to then deserialize it, but that would be quite silly.